# A non well formed numeric value encountered while subtracting two dates to give number of days

Tags: laravel

I want to output number of days from two dates.
For that i have tried

```
$date1 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));
$date2 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($check->date));
$diff = $date2 - $date1;
dd($diff);
```

It gives me error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the carbon package to easy your life.

At the top of your class:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

And then (Assuming that both dates are wellformed):

```
$date1 = Carbon::parse($date);
$date2 = Carbon::parse($check->date);
$diffInDays = $date2->diffInDays($date1); //Maybe you have to check what date is greater
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use PHP for the same:

```
$date1 = new \DateTime($date);
$date2 = new \DateTime($check->date);
$interval = $date2->diff($date1);
$days = $interval->format('%a');
```

References:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php